# Script to submit multiple slurm jobs from different, although matching, subdirectories

Tags: bash, while-loop, slurm

Lately I've been generating several series of input files to run calculations on a HPC using a Slurm queuing system. These calculations are all placed in subdirectories of the form `D001`, `D002`, etc. (`D`, followed by a three digit number, in numerical order). In these directories are my input files, always ending in `.inp` (for the series I'm looking at now, the files are all called `tma.h2s-2-vpt2-b97m-d4-qz_D001.inp`, etc., where the number in the input file matches the name of its subdirectory), and Slurm run scripts (these particular ones are all called `slurm-run-orca.job`).

So far, I've been laboriously running each of the calculations manually, by running (from the directory each of the subdirectories are placed in):

```
cd D001
sbatch -J tma.h2s-2-vpt2-b97m-D4-qz_D001 slurm-run-orca.job
cd ../D002
sbatch -J tma.h2s-2-vpt2-b97m-D4-qz_D002 slurm-run-orca.job
cd ../D003
sbatch -J tma.h2s-2-vpt2-b97m-D4-qz_D003 slurm-run-orca.job

etc.
```

This is very time consuming and, to be honest, makes my fingers very stiff. The last series I ran had 66 calculations, which I *did* get through eventually, but my current batch has 84...

Is there any way I can write a script to do this automatically? (Note, the input files are submitted *without* the `.inp` appended, despite the files all including a `.inp` extension.) I've searched for days to find a similar question/answer to this situation, but, funnily enough, I've not found anything that treats a problem this simple (at least, this problem *seems* simple — I could very well be mistaken, though)...

**Edit:** To clarify, the only files in the subdirectories are the job files and the input files, i.e.:

```
ls
D001   D002   D003   D004 ...

ls D001/
tma.h2s-2-vpt2-b97m-d4-qz_D001.inp   slurp-run-orca.job
```

So far, I have tried several things — `if`/`then` statements, `while` and `for` loops — but the fact is that I don't know enough about bash to get something like this to work (I can edit scripts, but I've never successfully written a script from scratch). The closest I've gotten to making the script work is:

```
#!/bin/bash

work_dir="pwd"
base=$1

n=001
submit_dir=$base$(( n ))

while ii in $submit_dir ; do
        cd $submit_dir
        squeue -J *.inp *.job
        cd $work_dir
        n=$(( $n + 1 ))
echo "Submitting calculations to queue"
done
```

I tried to add an if/then statement to make sure the loop would stop when it reached the end of the series (I have a feeling that would be unnecessary though), and to print out a `Could not find calculation subdirectories` when relevant, but then started focussing on getting the `while` loop to work. I *am* aware that what I have written so far will include the `.inp` extension, but I thought it would be worth getting the script to recognise that there were files in the directories first, and then worry about stripping the `.inp`...

Additionally, if possible, I would like to be able to submit the calculations in batches of 20, either with a specific time delay or by using a command like `./job-submission <base-name-of-input-files> 001-020` (for example), just so I don't clog up the queue (we have a very limited number of nodes available to us).

Any help getting this to work would be very appreciated!

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: Is there a `slurm-run-orca.job` and a single `.inp` file in each `DNNN` directory?

Comment: @Fravadona Yes, the directories are all for a single calculation each, i.e., directory ```D001``` contains ```xxx_D001.inp``` and ```slurm-run-orca.job```, and nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s nullglob

for workdir in "$@"
do
    pushd "$workdir" > /dev/null || continue

    for inpfile in *_"${PWD##*/}".inp
    do
        sbatch -J "${inpfile%.*}" slurm-run-orca.job
    done

    popd > /dev/null
done
```

Then you specify the directories from which you want to submit a job as argument:

```bash
./myscript.sh some/path/to/D*
```

---

###### Notes

- `pushd` and `popd` are bash builtins that you can use for `cd`ing to a directory and then return to the previous location.
- The environment variable `PWD` contains the path of the current directory; `${PWD##*/}` will expand to the last component of it (ie. everything up to the last `/` is stripped).

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I'm after (thanks for adding the notes). For some reason, though, I've come up against a ```-bash: ./job-submission.sh: permission denied``` error. I'm not quite sure what the issue might be... Possibly the ```/dev/null``` parts of it? Is there anything that can be replaced with without breaking the script?

Comment: It seems like you didn’t make the script executable: `chmod 755 job-submission.sh` , or call it like this: `bash job-submission.sh …`

Comment: That was it - it worked! I'd ```chmod```ed it on my laptop but not on the HPC (it's worked for other scripts), but I suppose this one was different? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Without having more information about what other `.job` files may need to be processed and whether or not there are other `.inp` files, it's difficult to provide a solution that will fit all of your use cases. Hopefully the following code can at least point you in the right direction or give you new insights.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0;
find -name "*_D*"|\
 while read fname;
  do i=$(($i+1));
  echo "sbatch -J ${fname%.*} slurm-run-orca.job;";
  if [ $i = "20" ];
   then echo "Sleeping 5 seconds";
   sleep 5;
   i=0;
  fi;
done
```

- `find -name` allows us to iterate over the directory structure according to a pattern
- The `while` loop allows us to loop over each file found
- `${fname%.*}` is shell parameter expansion allowing us to strip off the file extension a bit more simply than the `cut` command. This doesn't work in all shells however
- The final `if` command is used to support your desire to batch by 20 files followed by a time delay

Please note that this script makes certain assumptions that may not be true in your case. Please test thoroughly before removing the `echo` portion

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, at the risk of appearing stupid... how exactly do I run that script? As in, do I just enter the directory containing all of the subdirectories and execute the script? Also, I've edited the question slightly to clarify the contents of each (sub)directory.

Comment: Yes. You can run it from the directory that contains the folders with inp and job files.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, and I solved this using Python. Not just submitting jobs, but you run any shell command in 100s of folders at once. Please look at source code here. [ipyvasp set-dir](https://github.com/massgh/ipyvasp/blob/main/ipyvasp/cli.py#L107)

You can create a python file like multiple.py and then run as

```bash
python multiple.py set-dir */*matching-dirs -c "sbatch jobscript.sh"
```

Content of multiple.py (directly pasted from [ipyvasp.cli](https://github.com/massgh/ipyvasp/blob/main/ipyvasp/cli.py)

```py
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager 

from typing import List
from pathlib import Path

import typer
from typing_extensions import Annotated 

app = typer.Typer() 

@app.command("set-dir")
def _set_dir(
    paths: List[Path], command: Annotated[str, typer.Option("-c", "--command")] = "",
    ignore_error: Annotated[bool, typer.Option("-i", "--ignore-error")] = False
):
    """Set multiple directories like a for loop to execute a shell command within each of them.
    It will raise an error if the command fails in any of the directories. 
    To ignore the error and keep running in other directiories in sequence, use -i/--ignore-error. 
    It will raise the shell errors but python will go through all the directories.
    """
    from platform import system
    from subprocess import Popen

    os = system()  # operating system

    dirs = [f for f in paths if f.is_dir()]  # only dirs
    
    if not dirs:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "Provided paths do not exist or are not directories. Exiting..."
        )
    
    abs_paths = [f.absolute() for f in dirs] # absolute path is must but after filtering
    
    for path, d in zip(abs_paths,dirs):
        with set_dir(path):
            print(f"  {str(d)!r}")
            
            if command:
                if os == "Windows":
                    try:
                        p = Popen("pwsh.exe -NoProfile -c " + command, shell=False)
                    except:
                        p = Popen("powershell.exe -NoProfile -c " + command, shell=False)

                else:
                    p = Popen(command, shell=True)  # Linux, MacOS, shell to get args

                p.wait()
                if not ignore_error and p.returncode != 0:
                    raise RuntimeError(f"Command {command} failed in {path}. Exiting...") 

@contextmanager
def set_dir(path: str):
    """Context manager to work in some directory and come back.

    >>> with set_dir('some_folder'):
    >>>    do_something()
    >>> # Now you are back in starting directory
    """
    current = os.getcwd()  # not available in pathlib yet
    abspath = Path(path).resolve(strict=True).absolute()
    try:
        os.chdir(abspath)
        yield abspath
    finally:
        os.chdir(current)
```